# complex contour line Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to calculate this Integral where Z is an element of the Complex number. I
  think I need to find the residue because there is a singularity (the center of the contour is actually the singularity $z = -1 + i$) So I Believe I should find the residue. Is this all correct? and if it is, how do I find the residue?

$$c = -1 + i + e^{it} $$

$$ 0 < t \leq 2\pi$$

$$\int_c \frac1{(z^4 + 4)} dz$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $z_1$ is a simple singularity of $f(z)$

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z=z_1} f(z)= \lim_{z \to z_1} (z-z_1)f(z)$$

Comment: ahhhhh, thats right. thanks